# 7z extension for php?

Tags: php, compression, php-extension, 7zip

I can't find one and I don't know if any of [PHP Compression and Archive Extensions](http://no.php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php) will work.

Do you think I could use a [compression stream](http://no.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php) to read data from a 7z file?

UPDATE

- [7z forums](https://sourceforge.net/search/?group_id=14481&type_of_search=forums&words=php&search=Search) have a lot of requests for a php extension

Comment: If there is none, you can still use `exec`to interface with 7zip.

Comment: I know but I would prefer to find a solution without exec.

Comment: I considered writing an extension for 7-Zip, but... 7-Zip itself is Windows-only. p7zip, on the other hand, does not support Windows. So it would be difficult to write a portable extension. Then, if I remember correctly, there's the problem with the license being LGPL which is not ideal. Just using the LZMA SDK would be possible (I think it has a portable C API), but it's not the same thing.

Comment: I thought the same, but my C kung-fu is not strong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 7z file format can use various [compression algorithms](http://www.7-zip.org/7z.html), so you might be able to decompress the archive with one of the existing utilities for bzip2 or deflate.

I found a 7z PHP class as well, and you are lucky since it's [still being developed](http://forums.modem-help.co.uk/viewtopic.php?t=707&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=15). Here is the [latest version](http://download.modem-help.co.uk/non-modem/PHP/7z/7z.0.13.3.include.7z.php).

Comment: "At this moment it has been tested only on Linux, and restricts itself to listing an archive's contents. It can also return the Content-Type of all files. It can also return the Charset + contents of `text/...' files. It can also return the content of archives stored within the Archive."

Comment: Well that's better than nothing, I guess. Perhaps using the [LZMA SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) and [SWIG for PHP](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Php.html) could be an easy way to make a 7z extension. Although, I'm not sure that's considerably better than using a command-line program through exec().

Comment: Since this answer was posted, there's now a newer version of the PHP class, version 0.13.3 (latest version when answer was written was 0.13.1). I'm updating the "latest version" link in the answer to point to version 0.13.3, for those who (like me) will find this answer through a Google search later on.

Comment: However, it still doesn't extract files, just lists them. Which is a pretty major missing feature.

Comment: Yes, wouldn't accept that as an answer... still nothing.

Comment: The links are dead! I would really appreciate it if one of you could upload the source files, I need this so badly!