# Decompressing LZMA with PHP

Tags: php, compression, lzma

I have a load of SWF files compressed with LZMA that I would like to programatically decompress and read with PHP on my server.
Can someone direct me to a PHP LZMA SDK? I've googled for it, but have so far found nothing but references to a broken link ([7z extension for php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888497/7z-extension-for-php))

I have a working python module that manages to read headers of LZMA compressed SWFs but it requires a module called pyLZMA which doesn't seem to want to install on my server, and getting it to work locally was a massive pain in the arse so I'd much prefer a PHP solution if one exists.

Comment: If there isn't an LZMA class/library/extension for PHP you could always just call the command line `7z` application.

Comment: How exactly would I decode a ~8MB string via the command line?

Comment: You could save it as a temp file or `7z` may accept data from STDIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a library called [PHP-SevenZipArchive](https://github.com/cmanley/PHP-SevenZipArchive) which is a wrapper to 7za and 7zr binaries. Simple test scenario working for me in linux:

install p7zip package (`yum install p7zip` or similar)

create test compressed file in linux shell

```
echo "Compressed data" | lzma -z > compressed.string
```

download and unzip PHP-SevenZipArchive

```
wget https://github.com/cmanley/PHP-SevenZipArchive/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
```

create directory for decompressed output

```
mkdir out
```

create test php file

```
<?php
require "./PHP-SevenZipArchive-master/SevenZipArchive.php";
$archive = new SevenZipArchive('compressed.string', array('binary'=>'/usr/bin/7za'));
$archive->extractTo('out');
?>
```

`php -f ./index.php` will create file out/compressed

```
cat out/compressed
```

Compressed data

NOTE: My previous answer was deleted by moderators for its poor quality, although I already got a positive reputation for it. So I rewrote it completely in a detailed way. Hope this helps even more.